# including ABSPATH in every php file in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I was wondering how important is it to add this code in every php file?

```
if (!defined('ABSPATH')) { exit; }
```

this should prevent php file being accessed directly but without this code its also not accessible as I checked.

also if its important isn't there a better way of doing it?

thanks.

Comment: _“but without this code its also not accessible as I checked”_ - and how exactly did you check that? Just because you don’t see any actual _output_ when you call a PHP script, doesn’t necessarily mean the script isn’t _doing_ anything.

Comment: Wordpress never allow you to hit the script by direct url even you remove that piece of code

Comment: yes you are right wordpress wont allow it. so when does it become important to add this to php files?

Comment: WordPress doesn't "allow" or "disallow" access to scripts, that's your webserver's job.   Adding this to your scripts means they won't execute via direct URL, regardless of webserver configuration, and it happens to be the canonical way to do it.

Comment: oh that's right thanks

Answer (score 0):

ABSPATH is the absolute path to the WordPress directory. If you ask for a better way there is no better way except above.